# C# - Send UI reference to Task.Factory.StartNew();?

Tags: c#, multithreading, pass-by-reference, task

How would you send/pass instance references to a new task?

Let's say I've got this:

```
    public BlockingCollection<string> blockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<string>();
    textBox_txt.Text = "Result: ";
    public Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        foreach (string value in *???1*.blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            *???1*.blockingCollection.Take() 
            [...bla...]
            *???2*.Invoke(new updateTextBox_txtCallback(*???2*.updatetextBox_txt)
                          , new object[] { "THE RESULT!\r\n" });
        }                
    });
```

I'm guessing that somewhere in here `StartNew(() =>` I have to pass the references to the blockingContent and to the textBox. I've looked around but couldn't figure out the syntax. (it's quite hairy)

Help, please.

[Edit] So, if I call a static object from withing the Task, it obviously works; but I need the task to work with instances; namely the blockingCollection and the updateTextBox_txtCallback Invoke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your problem, with a workaround below. The problem is that you are using the Task as a field in your class  so it can only refer to static members, as the instance hasn't been constructed until the constructor is run (the field initializers are called before the class is initialized).
From the C# specification (10.5.5.2):

> A variable initializer for an instance
>   field cannot reference the instance
>   being created. Thus, it is a
>   compile-time error to reference this
>   in a variable initializer, as it is a
>   compile-time error for a variable
>   initializer to reference any instance
>   member through a simple-name. In the
>   example class A {     int x = 1;  int y =
>   x + 1;        // Error, reference to
>   instance member of this } the variable
>   initializer for y results in a
>   compile-time error because it
>   references a member of the instance
>   being created.

Basically you have two options:

1. Initialize your Task variable in the
   constructor
2. Use a method instead for retrieval

**Example:**

```
public class Foo
{
    public string myProperty = "foobar";
    public Task t;

    public Foo()
    {
        t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            myProperty = "test";

        });
    }

    //THIS won't compile
    //public Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    //{
    //    myProperty = "test";

    //});

    public Task GetTask()
    {
        Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            myProperty = "test";

        });
        return t;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know for a fact (tested) that one way to update the UI from a different thread (like a BgWorker) is to use Invoke and a Callback function; which I did `*???2*.Invoke(new updateTextBox_txtCallback(*???2*.updatetextBox_txt), new object[] { "THE RESULT!\r\n" });` If it were a BgWorker, the *???2* would have been replaced by "this." but in my current case, I need the main thread's instance reference.

Comment: I saw, and you temporarily "saved my ass"; as now I can continue coding while I wait for an answer. Thank you!

Comment: ^ Scratch that, You've figured it out and solved my problem completely. Thanks again. (good point also)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to pass the reference because C# supports [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29).  Simply using the variable holding that reference inside your `StartNew` block will cause the compiler to generate code that packages up you reference into state object that is passed to the anonymous method:

```
textBox_txt.Text = "Result: ";
public Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    // use textBox_txt in this block - the compiler
    // will handle the passing of actual reference to the
    // anonymous method for you                
});
```

I highly recommend [The Beauty of Closures](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx) for more information on this feature.

Now whether or not it is a good idea to close over a value that is a reference to a UI element is a completely different discussion.

Comment: That doesn't work. I need the references or else I get "a field initializer cannot reference a non static field" or "does not exist in teh current context".

Comment: That error must be coming from somewhere else - I don't see anything in the code you posted that would create that issue.

Comment: If I make the `public BlockingCollection` into `public STATIC BlockingCollection`, it works; but I can't have (and don't want) static vars in my code. The same goes for the textBox; it doesn't let me just write it without saying where it comes from..